# Scala Play Framework, where to create actors?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice, playframework-2.4

I am using Play 2.4.3 to create a CQRS web application. My simple question is: where should I create "global" actors? For instance: where to instantiate/inject the actor that is listening to events from the query side?

Comment: The best approach I've found is to use [dependency injected actor](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors) for root actors.

Comment: But where do I inject them? They are not related to any of the controllers..

Comment: Controller or not it is best for your main logic to be implemented as classes with injection instead of objects. And only in very last moment use the [InjectionBuilder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#GuiceInjectorBuilder)

Comment: You must use those actors somewhere. Use dependency injection in the classes where you use them.

Comment: If the actors are injected and must also maintain state across multiple requests, should they be declared as @Singleton?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate actors inside Play controllers.

**Example**

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka

object Application extends Controller {

  def actorIgniter = Action {
    val myActor = Akka.system.actorOf(ActorClassName.props())
    Ok
  }

}
```

In this way you will be able to instantiate `ActorClassName` calling the `actorIgniter` method via Play routes.
You are using Play helper (`play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka`) to instantiate actors inside the Akka actor system.

Another approach could be to instantiate the main actor inside the Play `Global` object.

```
object Global with GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Akka.system.actorOf(ActorClassName.props())
  }

}
```